# How do I call this method from a JavaBean in JSP using scriplets?

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I have a java bean class called "diaryApplication" which has the following code. My question is how do I call the saveUsers() method using jsp or scriptlets so that i can add another user to my xml??. My jsp contains the usual name,email, password etc etc.

I also have a users javabean which has an arraylist code allowing me to add users to an xml code everytime a user registers or signs up, this code is below diaryapplication.
    I also have a "user" Java bean the code is below that one.
please help me!

```
    package uts.wsd;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    public class DiaryApplication {

        private String filePath;
        private Users users;
        public DiaryApplication(String filepath, Users users) {
            super();
            this.filePath = filepath;
            this.users = users;
        }
        public DiaryApplication() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public String getFilepath() {
            return filePath;
        }
        public void setFilePath(String filePath) throws JAXBException, IOException {
            this.filePath = filePath;
            // This is the file path given to us.
            // We should use it

            // Load the users from the XML file...
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Users.class);
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filePath); // use the given file path
            users = (Users)u.unmarshal(fin); // This loads the "users" object
            fin.close();
        }
        public Users getUsers() {
            return users;
        }
        public void setUsers(Users users) {
            this.users = users;
        }
        // this is the code im trying to call???
        public void saveUsers() throws JAXBException, IOException{
            // Create the unmarshaller
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Users.class);
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

            // Now unmarshal the object from the file
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            users = (Users)u.unmarshal(fin); // This loads the "shop" object
            fin.close();
        }
    }
```

//// the code for users is below

```
    package uts.wsd;

    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "users")
    public class Users implements Serializable {
        // The list of user elements does NOT have an extra wrapper element.
        // See the comment in the XML file, and compare to the bookshop example.
        @XmlElement(name = "user")
        private ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

        public ArrayList<User> getList() {
            return list;
        }
        public void addUser(User user) {
            list.add(user);
        }
        public void removeUser(User user) {
            list.remove(user);
        }
        public User login(String email, String password) {
            // For each user in the list...
            for (User user : list) {
                if (user.getEmail().equals(email) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
                    return user; // Login correct. Return this user.
            }
            return null; // Login incorrect. Return null.
        }
    }
```

////////////User javabean

```
package uts.wsd;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @XmlElement(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @XmlElement(name = " favouritecolour")
    private String favouritecolour;

    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User(String email, String name, String password, String gender, String favouritecolour) {
        super();
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.favouritecolour = favouritecolour;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getFavouritecolour() {
        return favouritecolour;
    }

    public void setFavouritecolour(String favouritecolour) {
        this.favouritecolour = favouritecolour;
    }

}


package uts.wsd;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class TestJAXB implements Serializable {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Users users = new Users();
  users.addUser(new User("blaslsa@asda.com", "name", "password", "male", "green"));
  users.addUser(new User("average@bloggs.com", "Joe average", "password", "male", "yellow"));
  // Boilerplate code to convert objects to XML...
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Users.class);
  Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
  m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
  m.marshal(users, System.out);
 }
}
```

/// xml file for registered users

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <email>enemail@email.com</email>
        <name>name of user</name>
        <password>blahblah</password>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <favouriteColour>green</favouriteColour>
    </user>
    <user>
        <email>joe@bloggs.com</email>
        <name>Joe Bloggs</name>
        <password>foobar</password>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <favouriteColour>yellow</favouriteColour>
    </user>
     <user>
        <email>average@email.com</email>
        <name> my name </name>
        <password>my password</password>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <favouriteColour>yellow</favouriteColour>
    </user>
</users>
```

/// this is the registration page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Register</h1>

<form action="welcome.jsp" method="POST">

<table>
<tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Full name</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</td></tr>
<tr><td>Favourite colour</td><td><select name="favcol"><option>red<option>green</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Agree to TOS</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="tos"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Register"></td></tr>
</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>

/// this is the welcome page for users

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="uts.wsd.*"%>


<%
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
String favouritecolour = request.getParameter("favcol");
String agreeTOS = request.getParameter("tos");
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="<%= favouritecolour %>">

<%  
    if(agreeTOS != null)
    {
        User user = new User(email,name,password,gender,favouritecolour);
        session.setAttribute("user",user);

%>




<p>Welcome, <%= name %>!</p>

<p>Your Email is <%= email %>.</p>

<p>Your password is <%= password %>.</p>

<p>Your gender is <%= gender %>.</p>

<p>Your favourite colour is <%= favouritecolour %>.</p>

<p>Click<a href="index.jsp">Here</a> to go back to mainpage</p>
<%
}
else
{
%>
<p>Sorry, you must agree to the Terms of Services.</p>
<p>Click <a href="register.jsp">here</a> to go back.</p>
<%
}
%>

</body>
</html>

// this is the login page for users

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<table>
<form action="loginaction.jsp" method="POST">
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="Submit" name="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

//////this is my index.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="uts.wsd.User"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Diary Keeper</h1>
<% User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user"); %>
    <% if(user != null){%>
    <div style= "text-align: right; border: solid 1px black;">
    You are logged in as <%= user.getName() %> &lt; <%= user.getEmail() %>&gt;
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
    <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
    </div>  
        <% } else { %>

    <div style="text-align: right; border: solid 1px black;">
    <p>You are not logged in. <a href="register.jsp"> Register</a> | <a href="login.jsp"> Login</a>
    </div>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

//////// this is my loginaction page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="uts.wsd.*"%>

    <% String filePath = application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/users.xml"); %>
<jsp:useBean id="diaryApp" class="uts.wsd.DiaryApplication" scope="application">
    <jsp:setProperty name="diaryApp" property="filePath" value="<%=filePath%>"/>
</jsp:useBean>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String password = request.getParameter("password");

Users users = diaryApp.getUsers();
User user = users.login(email,password);

if(user != null){
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
%>

<p>Login successful Click<a href="index.jsp">here</a> to go to main page</p>

<%} else { %>

<p> Password or username incorrect Click<a href="login.jsp"> here</a> to try again.</p>

<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So far I see some POJOs two of them can be serialized to XML using JAXB. What I am missing here is the part that would allow the POJOs to be part of a web application.

Comment: check again i edited the code...

Comment: You have a main method there to test the application. This does make no sense in the context of a web application. A web application would consist of some Java classes some views (HTML, JSP), a web.xml and probably some bean configuration.

Comment: I have alot of files say 5 html files in total and one xml. Do you have an email address I can send this too?

Comment: Please post all the relevant information in your question, so everyone can see it.

Comment: Just don't use scriptlets.

Comment: Is this 1999?  Scriptlets?  No one should write scriptlet code.  No email addresses or private dialog.  Post a simple, self-contained example here instead of this wall o' code.